# Shell: How to replace something of a text with the saved variable value

Tags: regex, shell, sed, awk, grep

I saved a value by shell command:
For example:

```
timeoutvalue=`echo "timeout=2.0"`
```

And I have to grep the value of timeout from another text, and replace it with this timeoutvalue.
For example, the text is egtest:

```
<host ip="255.255.255.0" name="testhost" description="hostfortest" connection="xmlrpc" timeout=4.0/>
```

I want to grep the value of timeout from the above text and replace the value of `timeout=4.0` by `timeout=2.0`(the value I saved as variable by shell command).

My problem is:
(1)for a simple test, I want to replace the value of timeout=4.0 with $timeoutvalue.
So my command is:

`sed 's/timeout=4.0/$timeoutvalue/g' egtext`.

But it seems the text become:

```
<host ip="255.255.255.0" name="testhost" description="hostfortest" connection="xmlrpc" $timeoutvalue/>
```

Could anybody tell me why it is wrong?

(2)For this problem, I have to first grep `timeout=4.0` from the text, and replace the value `4.0` to the saved variable value(in my example:2.0).
I thought but I don't know which command to use to realize this(awk? sed?)
Because the filed of the text isn't certain,(for example, in this text, timeout is in `$5`, but maybe in another text, it maybe changed into `$6`). I mean it may be changed into:

```
<host ip="255.255.255.0" name="testhost" description="hostfortest" connection="xmlrpc" type="onebox" timeout=4.0/>
```

Could anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single quote does not allow variable interpolation, so use double quotes as:

```
sed "s/timeout=4.0/$timeoutvalue/g" egtext
```

**EDIT:**

Consider

```
who='world'
echo "Hello $who" # prints Hello world
echo 'Hello $who" # prints Hello $who
```

as seen single quotes does not allow variable substitution. It treats `$who` literally as a dollar followed by `who`. But double quote behaves differently, when it sees `$who` it realizes that `who` is a variable and replaces `$who` with its value.

Comment: codaddict,thanks a lot for your answer.
It seems I still haven't fully acknowledge the difference betwween  Single quote and Double quote.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Single quotes inhibit variable expansion.

```
sed 's/timeout=4.0/'"$timeoutvalue"'/g' egtext
```

Comment: lgnacio, thanks for your method and quick answer.
But could you please tell me way we use another Single quotes besides the Double quotes of $timeoutvalue?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would write your code as the following.

```
timeoutvalue='timeout=2.0'
sed "s/timeout=[.0-9]*/${timeoutvalue}/" egtext
```

Comment: z1x2, many thanks for your nice answer.
In fact, its just what I want.