# Regex: Help with extracting a filed from the text and replace the value of the field

Tags: regex, shell, sed, awk, grep

I have to extract a parameter from a configuration file, and replace its values with another given value.
The config file is:

```
<host ip="200.200.200.200" name="testhost" description="test server" type="TEST_Duplex " connection="xmlrpc" xmldefaulttimeout="2.0" xmlspecifictimeout ="8.0"/>
```

I have to replace the value of `xmldefaulttimeout="2.0"` with another value, for example: `xmldefaulttimeout="4.0"`.

As in the text, xmldefaulttimeout="2.0", but in fact, the value "2.0" is not certain. It may be another uncertain value. So I have to grep the value of xmldefaulttimeout and replace it with another given value (for example:4.0).

I think I have to use sed or awk. But I'm sorry my tried commands can't realize this.
Could anybody help me with this? Thanks!
I'm sorry I just begin to learn shell:-)

Comment: Is using regular expressions with shell a **must**? Do you have access to a scripting language with XML tools, say Perl/Python/Ruby? Any one of them can make your work much easier. Just a thought.

Comment: Manoj, thanks.
I think using regular expressions with shell is a must.
Thank you for suggestions. I will investigate them then.

Comment: Why this question? You posted a pretty similar question 2 hours ago ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3581169/shell-how-to-replace-something-of-a-text-with-the-saved-variable-value )

Comment: maxschlepzig, I'm sorry, yes I indeed post a similar question 2 hours ago. 
But I thought maybe I'm not clear enough to express clearly. Because at that time, most people respond only to my 1st question.
So I ask the similar question again.
Maybe I should edited it, but not ask again.
I'm very sorry.
I will pay attention next time.


Besides, thanks to all who look into this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
input='<host ip="200.200.200.200" name="testhost" description="test server" type="TEST_Duplex " connection="xmlrpc" xmldefaulttimeout="2.0" xmlspecifictimeout ="8.0"/'

new_value='xmldefaulttimeout="4.0"'

echo $input | sed "s/xmldefaulttimeout=\"[0-9.]*\"/$new_value/"
```

To match any value for xmldefaulttimeout you'll have to use a regex: `xmldefaulttimeout=\"[0-9.]*\"`

- `xmldefaulttimeout=` : Matched
  literally
- `\"` : To match a literal `"`, you need
  to escape the `"` to prevent
  premature ending of the pattern.
- `[0-9.]` : Char class to match any
  digit or a period
- `*` : zero or more of the previous char.

Comment: codaddict, thanks again for your detailed information.
Indeed, I didn't though up to use regex to realize this.
I just begin to learn shell. Many thanks for your detailed information for both this question and last question!

Answer (score 1):

bash 3.2+

```
#!/bin/bash   

new='xmldefaulttimeout="4.0"'
exec 4<"file"
while read -r line <&4
do
  case "$line" in
   *"xmldefaulttimeout="*)
     [[ $line =~ "(.*)(xmldefaulttimeout=\".[^ \t]*\")(.*)" ]]
     echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${new}${BASH_REMATCH[3]}
      ;;
  esac
done
exec 4<&-
```

Comment: ghostdog74, thanks again for your nice and helpful answer!
And it works:-)
Your script helps me learn much more.
I just begin to learn shell, thanks for your help!